# how to remove this [object promise] tag from your camera window in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, object, promise

In this code when you run the webpage, countown starts from 5 till 0 and then the camera window opens to capture your picture, but in that camera window this [object promises] tag also gets flashed. Any insight would be appreciated to remove this line from my camera window.
I am a newbee to js.
Code:

```
<body>
    
    <div class="container">
        <h1 id="count">5</h1>
    </div>

    <!-- Stream video via webcam -->
    <div class="video-wrap">
        <video id="video" playsinline autoplay></video>
    </div>

    <!-- Trigger canvas web API -->
    <div class="controller">
        <button id="snap">Capture</button>
    </div>

    <!-- Webcam video snapshot -->
    <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="480"></canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        'use strict';

        const video = document.getElementById('video');
        const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        const snap = document.getElementById('snap');
        const errorMsgElement = document.getElementById('span#ErrorMsg');

        const constraints = {
            audio: true,
            video: {
                width: 1280, height: 720
            }
        };
        async function init() {
            try {
                const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
                handleSuccess(stream);
            }
            catch (e) {
                errorMsgElement.innerHTML = `navigator.getUserMedia.error:${e.toString()}`;

            }
        }

        // Success
        function handleSuccess(stream) {
            window.stream = stream;
            video.srcObject = stream;
        }

        var counter = 5;
        setInterval(function () {
            counter--;
            if (counter >= 0) {
                var id = document.getElementById("count");
                id.innerHTML = counter;
            }
            if (counter == 0) {
                id.innerHTML = init();
            }
        }, 1000);

        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        snap.addEventListener("click", function () {
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 640, 480);
        });

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`init` is an async function, meaning that it will return a promise first and then, that promise will resolve into something else when the asynchronous execution is complete. When you are setting your `innerHTML` to the return value of `init`, you are not awaiting the promise to resolve (or reject).

To solve this issue, you should set your callback of the `setInterval` to be an async function and await the response of the `init`.

```js
setInterval(async () => {
    counter--;
    if (counter >= 0) {
        var id = document.getElementById("count");
        id.innerHTML = counter;
    }
    if (counter == 0) {
        id.innerHTML = await init();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: your solution does removed [object promises] tag but then it added another tag [undefined] on my camera window

Comment: That's because `init` function does not return a value. If I understand correctly, after the count down reaches 0, you want to remove the counter from the screen and initialize the stream. To do that, just set `id.innerHTML = ""` and call `await init()` on the next line.